# Can't convert object to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, data-cleaning

I need to convert an object to a float to combine some numbers later, but can't seem to to do it. I am working from file on my machine but data is on the web if anyone wants to reproduce.

[original csv](https://data.world/exercises/data-wrangling-exercise-1/workspace/file?filename=Crime_2015.csv)

Tried converting as it came from csv

```
crime = pd.read_csv("C://college_data/nrippner-opportunity-project-use-case/Crime_2015.csv", dtype={'PropertyCrime':float})
print(crime.head())
crime.dtypes
```

seems to be a problem with the 'safe rule'

I also tried

```
crime['PropertyCrime'] = crime.PropertyCrime.astype(float)
```

and it just said can't convert object to float

any ideas?

As requested in comments:

```
crime = pd.read_csv("C://college_data/nrippner-opportunity-project-use-case/Crime_2015.csv")

print(crime.PropertyCrime.head())
crime.dtypes
```

[image]

Sorry I apologize if there is a better way than screenshot to post from jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The numbers are not properly inferred because of the `,`.

- Use the `thousands` parameter in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

#### Sample data

```py
                    MSA ViolentCrime  Murder  Rape  Robbery  AggravatedAssault PropertyCrime Burglary    Theft  MotorVehicleTheft State         City
     Abilene, TX M.S.A.        412.5     5.3  56.0     78.4              272.8       3,609.0    852.0  2,493.6              263.4    TX      Abilene
       Akron, OH M.S.A.        238.4     5.1  38.2     75.2              119.8       2,552.4    575.3  1,853.0              124.1    OH        Akron
      Albany, GA M.S.A.        667.9     7.8  30.4    157.9              471.8       3,894.1  1,099.6  2,652.8              141.7    GA       Albany
      Albany, OR M.S.A.        114.3     2.5  28.2     20.7               63.0       3,208.4    484.6  2,476.1              247.7    OR       Albany
 Albuquerque, NM M.S.A.        792.6     6.1  63.8    206.7              516.0       4,607.8    883.4  3,047.6              676.9    NM  Albuquerque
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/27rl5szyyfje5zv5dg2us5c5vqlcfz', thousands=',')
```

- Float types are now properly inferred.

```py
                    MSA  ViolentCrime  Murder  Rape  Robbery  AggravatedAssault  PropertyCrime  Burglary   Theft  MotorVehicleTheft State         City
     Abilene, TX M.S.A.         412.5     5.3  56.0     78.4              272.8         3609.0     852.0  2493.6              263.4    TX      Abilene
       Akron, OH M.S.A.         238.4     5.1  38.2     75.2              119.8         2552.4     575.3  1853.0              124.1    OH        Akron
      Albany, GA M.S.A.         667.9     7.8  30.4    157.9              471.8         3894.1    1099.6  2652.8              141.7    GA       Albany
      Albany, OR M.S.A.         114.3     2.5  28.2     20.7               63.0         3208.4     484.6  2476.1              247.7    OR       Albany
 Albuquerque, NM M.S.A.         792.6     6.1  63.8    206.7              516.0         4607.8     883.4  3047.6              676.9    NM  Albuquerque
```

```py
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 378 entries, 0 to 377
Data columns (total 12 columns):
MSA                  378 non-null object
ViolentCrime         377 non-null float64
Murder               378 non-null float64
Rape                 378 non-null float64
Robbery              378 non-null float64
AggravatedAssault    377 non-null float64
PropertyCrime        372 non-null float64
Burglary             374 non-null float64
Theft                375 non-null float64
MotorVehicleTheft    378 non-null float64
State                378 non-null object
City                 373 non-null object
dtypes: float64(9), object(3)
```